# how to create method in enum field with javassist

Tags: java, reflection, enums, javassist

I'm trying to insert a method dynamically in an enum.

```
 private void loadEnums(ServletContextEvent sce) {
    List<Class<?>> classes = CPScanner.scanClasses(new ClassFilter().packageName("br.com.alinesolutions.anotaai.*").annotation(EnumSerialize.class));
    CtClass ctClass = null;
    EnumMemberValue enumMemberValue;
    try {
        for (Class<?> clazz : classes) {
            if (!Enum.class.isAssignableFrom(clazz)) {
                throw new RuntimeException("class " + clazz + " is not an instance of Enum");
            }
            ClassPool.getDefault().insertClassPath(new ClassClassPath(clazz));
            ctClass = ClassPool.getDefault().get(clazz.getName());
            for (CtField field : ctClass.getFields()) {
                System.out.println(field);
                //CtMethod m = CtNewMethod.make("public String getType() { return this.toString(); }", ctClass);
                //ctClass.addMethod(m);
            }
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

how to create a method in enum field?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume that you try to create a method within an enumeration, i.e.

```
enum Foo {
  BAR {
    void qux() { }
  }
}
```

The Java compiler creates such a method by creating a specific class that subclasses `Foo` and adds the method to this class. You would need to remove the `final` modifier from `Foo`, create such a subclass and replace the static initializer that creates the enum field for this.

Comment: the method toString, for example. it's created in all types of enum.
if i create the three methods in enum class. it's possible recompile the enum class?

you have a example for your solution?

Comment: No, you can inherit methods from the base class.

Answer (score 0):

I use RESTEasy for serializing enum objects and need to put the annotation

> @JsonFormat(shape = JsonFormat.Shape.OBJECT)

and create a method with the anotation

> @JsonCreator

need to create a method for each enum for this.

I have to create the methods, fromObject getProperty and getType dynamically for all enums, the method fromObject is static. that is, a difference to create this method. I created a annotation and when the context initialize want build these methods

```
package br.com.alinesolutions.anotaai.metadata.model.domain;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonCreator;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonFormat;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonNode;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.node.JsonNodeType;

@JsonFormat(shape = JsonFormat.Shape.OBJECT)
public enum TipoAcesso {

    EMAIL("E-Mail"),
    TELEFONE("Telefone");

    private String descricao;

    private TipoAcesso(String descricao) {
        this.descricao = descricao;
    }
    public String getDescricao() {
        return descricao;
    }
    // TODO - Adicionar metodos dinamicamente
    public String getType() {
        return this.toString();
    }

    public String getPropertieKey() {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder("enum.");
        sb.append(this.getClass().getName()).append(".");
        sb.append(toString());
        return sb.toString().toLowerCase();
    }

    @JsonCreator
    public static TipoAcesso fromObject(JsonNode node) {
        String type = null;
        if (node.getNodeType().equals(JsonNodeType.STRING)) {
            type = node.asText();
        } else {
            if (!node.has("type")) {
                throw new IllegalArgumentException();
            }
            type = node.get("type").asText();
        }
        return valueOf(type);
    }
}
```